# (Django) How to create a verification mixin that references two models?

Tags: python, django, authentication, permissions, mixins

I have two classes *Organisation*, and *Staff* in addition to the *User* class. I want to create a mixin called "UserIsAdminMixin" that checks whether the user logged in has the role "admin" in a specific Organisation.

**The classes (simplified)**

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Staff(models.Model):
    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        ADMIN      = 'ADMIN', "Admin"
        STAFF      = 'STAFF', "Staff"

    user         = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, related_name="staff_profiles", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey('organisations.Organisation', db_index=True, related_name="staff", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role         = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Role.choices, default=Role.STAFF)
```

I then currently have this for my UserIsAdmin mixin:

```
class UserIsAdminMixin:

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.staff_profiles.filter(organisation=self.get_object(), role=Staff.Role.ADMIN):
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
```

This works great for this view:

*organisations.views.py (URL: organisation/<int:pk>)*

```
class OrganisationDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, UserIsAdminMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Organisation
    template_name= "organisations/detail.html"
    login_url = "login"
```

But I'd also like it to work for this view as well, which it obviously doesn't as self.get_object() returns a Staff object in this case when it's expecting an Organisation object:

*staff.views.py (URL: organisation/<int:pk_alt>/staff/<int:pk>)*

```
class StaffDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, UserIsAdminMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Staff
    template_name="staff/detail.html"
    login_url = "login"
```

I was able to make changes to the mixin to get it to work in the second scenario but not the first:

```
class UserIsAdminMixin:

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.staff_profiles.filter(organisation__pk=self.kwargs['pk_alt']), role=Staff.Role.ADMIN):
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
```

So is there any way I can change the mixin so it works for **both** *Organisation* and *Staff* models to check that the User is a staff member with the role of admin for a given organisation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many Thanks,

*GoingRoundInCircles*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a possible solution is to have a `get_organisation_id()` method in both your views.

**Your mixin:**

```py
class UserIsAdminMixin:

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        organisation_id = self.get_organisation_id()
        if self.request.user.staff_profiles.filter(organisation_pk=organisation_id, role=Staff.Role.ADMIN):
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
```

**StaffDetail**:

```py
class StaffDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, UserIsAdminMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Staff
    template_name="staff/detail.html"
    login_url = "login"

    def get_organisation_id(self):
        return self.kwargs.get('pk_alt')
```

**OrganisationDetail:**

```py
class OrganisationDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, UserIsAdminMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Organisation
    template_name= "organisations/detail.html"
    login_url = "login"

    def get_organisation_id(self):
        return self.get_object().id
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I never would have thought of this! One quick question, I also have CRUD views for Staff and Organisation, all that require UserIsAdmin, is there a way I can cleanly add the get_organisation_id() method to each of them without having to define the method in each view? I know I should be able to extend a class but the base class for the different views is different so not sure how...(as the base class would be either generic.CreateView, generic.UpdateView, generic.DetailView etc.). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Oh wait, I think I've done it... I made another mixin as an abstract class with the get_organisation_id method and then added that mixin to the views as well. Is that the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: If there are a lot of views, then I think the most optimal way would be to implement the `get_organisation_id()` method in the models. And in the `UserIsAdminMixin` you can have it via `self.get_object().get_organisation_id()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm not sure if I'm missing something but when I add the method to the Staff model instead I get the following error: 'Staff' object has no attribute 'kwargs'. I tried changing the code for the method to `return self.organisation.id` but then it would allow access to the staff even when the URL pointed to an organisation that the staff wasn't a member of but the user was an admin of so that's not the right thing to do... Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or do you have any suggestions? Thanks!